# Interrupt the thread which is making HTTP call in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, http, threadpoolexecutor

I am writing a java program to make an HTTP call to server in a different thread. The following code I am executing in a separate Callable task in thread pool executor.

```
public static class MyRunnable implements Callable<Boolean>{

    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.myserver.com");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                            return response == 200;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the server does not respond or server responds very slowly. Because of this server's behavior, both connection timeout and read time outs never happens.

Hence I want to monitor this task (running in thread pool executor), and interrupt the thread after sometime and make sure that I remove this task from the pool so that thread pool does not contain this task and frees up all the resources taken by this thread.

I tried `Future` of java like following

```
 ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new      ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10));
 Future<Boolean> f = tpe.submit(new MyRunnable());
  try {
        Boolean success = f.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With this code, I get `TimeoutException` from the `f.get` call after 5000 milliseconds if the thread which is handling `MyRunnable` task does not respond. But I can see that, the task will be kept running in the thread pool executor, if it is stuck at `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()`.

When I tried `f.cancel(true)`, it is not interrupting the thread when the task is stuck at `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` method call. I understand that thread will get interrupted only when it tests for it in the next available opportunity. Hence I guess `future.cancel` does not help in this case.

So how do I come out of this call (by interacting with thread pool executor) and make sure that the task is removed from the pool and the corresponding thread is free to handle different tasks ?

Thanks for the reply in advance.

Thanks,

Raagu

Comment: First, use `Executors.newXXX` rather than the constructor. Second, your question is unclear - you have a timeout set at 5 seconds (use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)` there rather than `5000`), so the connection will timeout after 5 seconds. What do you mean by _the task will be kept running in the thread pool_?

Comment: Boris, even 5000 milliseconds (which is 5 seconds) is getting timed out after 5 seconds. No problem with that. And after future.get() times out, the thread which is handling the callable task in the pool, will be keep running executing that task. I want that thread should leave that callable task and comes back to the pool. Executors.newXXX does not help. I am not able to free up the thread if it is stuck at http call.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the sample code of your `MyRunnable`, it does not compile, the return True/False is missing. Also the second code sample does not compile, the constructor that accepts a String is missing for the runnable.

Comment: cheffe, Compilation removed.

Comment: FYI: The code ran against my Jersey based slow service times out in 5 seconds at  conn.getResponseCode(). You may use fiddler to findout whats happening at wire level.

Comment: Dhana, It times out properly when I connect to different servers. But  Unfortunately, my own proxy server (not www.myserver.com) neither  connection times out, nor read times out. It responds very very slowly. Hence I wanted the calling client (thread) should be suspended after some time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can share the connection with another thread which would call disconnect() on it after the time outs. So, it should be something like that:

```
static class ConnectionStopper implements Runnable {

    private final HttpURLConnection conn;

    ConnectionStopper(HttpURLConnection conn) {
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}

...

ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
...
// Submit your MyRunnable, then schedule a ConnectionStopper
service.schedule(new ConnectionStopper(conn), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Artyom, conn.disconnect is also not suspending the conn.getResponseCode call.

Comment: Does adding System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"); before opening a connection help?

Answer (score 0):

Call [Future.cancel(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) in the case of a timeout exception. This will interrupt the work you are doing in your runnable. This should result in an [InterruptedIOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html) being thrown in your callable by conn.getResponseCode().

Comment: Brett, I tried future.cancel(true). It did not work. future cancel sends the interrupt signal to thread. But the conn.getResponseCode() is not honoring it. Hence conn.getResponseCode() continue to run. I am looking for something where thread pool makes the thread stop doing that callable task no matter what work it is doing.

Comment: You are basically at the mercy of the InputStream.read implementation used by getResponseCode. It is blocking IO. By setting a connection timeout and read timeout, however, you should not wait much longer than the sum of those 2 values. Generally speaking, the response status is about the first thing returned from an http request. So the read timeout effectively defines how long you will wait once a connection is established.